# how to insert variable in SQL into LIKE query in flask?

Tags: python, sql, flask

I'm trying to make a search bar, which means that I have to make it to take incomplete data. I have this code, but for some reason it gives me a syntax error, when I try to print it into terminal, in order to look at it. Any ideas what could be wrong? I think I made a mistake when I was putting the variables in, but I can't really find anything about it on google.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
BookSearch = db.execute(text("SELECT * FROM books WHERE 
        (isbn LIKE :search) OR (title LIKE :search) OR (author LIKE :search)", 
        { "search": '%' + search + '%'}).fetchall()
print(BookSearch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text()` does not have a close parenthesis which is likely causing your syntax error.

I'm assuming it should go right after the `"` and the dictionary is passed to `execute()`

```
BookSearch = db.execute(text("SELECT * FROM books WHERE 
        (isbn LIKE :search) OR (title LIKE :search) OR (author LIKE :search)"), 
        {"search": '%' + search + '%'}).fetchall()
print(BookSearch)
```